# React axios api call: How can I return multiple parameters in a url?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

Wasn't sure how to ask this..

How can I return, say, people/0-15? I don't want just people/0, I'd like to access people 0-15, etc

I want to return multiple people. What should I be doing here?

```
function getData() {
    return axios.get("https://www.blablahtest.com/api/orders");
  }

function getPerson() {
    return axios.get(`https://www.blablahtest.com/api/people/0`); <----
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.all([getData(), getPerson()]).then(
      axios.spread(function(item, person) {
        setData(item.data);
        setPersonData(person.data);
      })
    );
  }, []);
```

Comment: Do you have access to the API? If so, you can just create an endpoint that does this for you `"https://www.blablahtest.com/api/people/[start]/[end]"`

Comment: It's impossible to say because we don't know what the API you're interacting with allows. You should look at the documentation and figure out what's possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a function called getPeople to set up an array of Axios GET's, then execute them all in your axios.all? Not an ideal solution since you need to make many requests, but if you don't have the ability to modify the backend then it'll get you what you need...

```
    function getPeople(start, end) {
      const requestArray= [];
      for ( let i = start; i < end; i++ ) {
        peopleArray.push(() => axios.get(`https://www.blablahtest.com/api/people/${i}`))
      }
     return peopleArray;
}
```

In useEffect:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.all(...getPeople(0,15)).then(
      axios.spread(function(people) {
        setPersonData(people);
      })
    );
  }, []);
```

Something like that.... Might need some tweaks as I didn't get a chance to test it. Good luck!

Comment: This doesn't quite work but it seems like the closest I've gotten to it yet..

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `axios.spread` (it will be removed in future versions https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1042)

You can try below:

```
function getData() {
  return axios.get("https://www.blablahtest.com/api/orders");
}

function getPerson() {
  return axios.get("https://www.blablahtest.com/api/people/0");
}

useEffect(() => {
  Promise.all([getData(), getPerson()]).then((item, person) => {
    setData(item.data);
    setPersonData(person.data);
  })
}, []);
```

I hope it helps.